# Create many tar files from a directory with 500000 files

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, tar, parallel-processing

I have a directory containing around 500k files, and want to slice them into `t` tar files.

Put formally, let's call the files `file_0, ..., file_{N-1}`, where `N` around 500k. I want to create `t` tar files each containing `T=N/t` files, where the i-th tar file contains

```
file_(i*N), ..., file_((i+1)*N - 1),    i in {0, ..., t-1}
```

What's an efficient way to do this? I was going to write a Python script that just loops over the `N` files and divides them into `t` folders, and then calls `tar` in each, but this feels very unoptimal. I have many cores on the server and feel like this should happen in parallel.

Comment: `xjobs` has the `-l` option to combine several input arguments for each job.  You'd have to separately count the files and divide by `N` prior to that, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python `concurrent` library which is designed to process a request queue among all or some threads, eating the queue until all jobs are entirely executed.

1. Generate a big list of list of files, like `[ [f0..f0-1], [fn..f2n-1]..]`
2. Use a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) to eat this list with all many thread your computer has. This can look like this:

```python
import os
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import subprocess
import itertools
import math


def main(p, num_tar_files):
    files = list(split_files_in(p, num_tar_files))
    tar_up = tar_up_fn(p)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(files)) as executor:
        archives = list(executor.map(tar_up, itertools.count(), files))
        print("\n {} archives generated".format(len(archives)))


def split_files_in(p, num_slices):
    files = sorted(os.listdir(p))
    N = len(files)
    T = int(math.ceil(N / num_slices))  # means last .tar might contain <T files
    for i in range(0, N, T):
        yield files[i:i+T]


def tar_up_fn(p):
    def tar_up(i, files):
        _, dir_name = os.path.split(p)
        tar_file_name = "{}_{:05d}.tar".format(dir_name, i)
        print('Tarring {}'.format(tar_file_name))
        subprocess.call(["tar", "-cf", tar_file_name] + files, cwd=p)
        return tar_file_name
    return tar_up


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
```

Comment: Thanks @fabian789 for having edited the draft script of the answer with the real-life working one you made of it.

Comment: It's nice to see fruitful cooperation. +1 for the answer and the question.

Answer (score 0):

#### using zsh to create lists for tar

Hope I understood what your trying to do. `t=731` was just a number I picked out of the air.  Hack as needed. The following creates multiple files with `t` file names or the last file with the remaining file names if not equal to `t`.

```
Var=(*(.)) # glob files in current directory
VarSorted=(${(on)Var})  # numeric sort
fn=1  # Tar list file number
t=731  # Number of files in each tar file
for (( i = 1 ; i <= ${#VarSorted} ; i = i + t ))
do
  print -l -- ${VarSorted[$i,$i+$t-1]} > /tmp/tar_file_list_${(l:5::0:)fn}
  (( fn++ ))
done
```

Use the `tar` command's `-t` or `--files-from`(short/long form) option to generate each tar file. This too can also be scripted.