# run command on multiple threads

Tags: centos, multi-threaded

I am running a command (pngquant to be precise: https://github.com/pornel/pngquant) in a terminal window. I noticed, that if I open 4 terminal windows, and run pngquant command in each of them, I get 4x speed increase, effectively compression 4 times as many images in the same time as before.

So I used this approach and assigned each pngqunat process a portion of images I want to compress, effectively creating multiple processes on multiple threads

Can you run command on multiple threads without doing this tricks that I did? I would like to just say "run pngquant compression on all this images and use all threads available."

Comment: You could employ `parallel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the exact same system [this recent question](https://superuser.com/questions/1207514/create-many-tar-files-from-a-directory-with-500000-files/1207603) required. The answer given (python concurrent-based script) will perfectly fit your needs once adapted a small bit for your simpler case.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my previous comment into an answer.

[Gnu parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel) is the command line tool conceived to run jobs simultaneusly thus making use of multiple threads, cores, CPUs, PCs. [xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html) now offers similar functionality with the addition of the `-P` switch.

I ran a test for you on a two core [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), using `pngquant` to convert a bunch of `.png` files (126 images averaging 9MB in size).

`pngquant *.png` took 26 minutes.

`find . -iname "*.png" | parallel pngquant {}` took 14 minutes.

`top` shows the parallel execution of two `pngquant` commands at a time:

```
  PID USER    PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 5808 user    20   0   70948  59164   2140 R 100.0  2.9   0:03.49 pngquant
 5811 user    20   0   70952  61000   2024 R  99.3  3.0   0:05.67 pngquant
```